# Pickle errors with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm converting some code from Python **2** to Python **3**, and I have hard time with a pickle problem! Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class test(str):

        def __new__(self, value, a):
                return (str.__new__(self, value))

        def __init__(self, value, a):
                self.a = a


if __name__ == '__main__':
        import pickle
        t = test("abs", 5)
        print (t)
        print( t.a)

        wdfh = open("./test.dump", "wb")
        pickle.dump(t, wdfh)
        wdfh.close()

        awfh = open("./test.dump", "rb")
        newt = pickle.load(awfh)
        awfh.close()

        print (t)
        print (newt.a)
```

This works just fine with Python 2 but I have the following error with Python 3:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 21, in
>
> ```
> newt = pickle.load(awfh)
> ```
>
> TypeError: **new**() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

I do not understand what is the difference, any idea?

Comment: Are you reading things pickled by python 2 in python 3? They are not compatible.

Comment: No! The script is executed in Python3 or in Python2, so the reading / writing is done in the same version.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your code only works with protocol 0 or 1.  By default, Python 2 uses protocol 0, whereas Python 3 uses protocol 3.

For protocol 2 and above you can't have additional arguments to the `__new__` method unless you implement the `__getnewargs__` method.

In this case simply adding:

```
    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return (str(self),self.a)
```

should do the trick.

Or you could stick with protocol 0 or 1 and change the dump call:

```
    pickle.dump(t, wdfh, 0)
```